# What does MLD stand for?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, terminology

I've seen some references to the term "MLD" but have failed to find a definition in any list of MTG terminology or slang.  What does this mean?

Comment: In general when asking questions like this it can help to share the context where you saw the term, in case other people can figure it out from context.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All of the [top hits on Google](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&channel=trow&q=mtg+mld) refer to MLD as "mass land destruction", i.e. cards like [Armageddon](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bArmageddon%5d).

Or, to quote one of the [moderators on MTGSalvation](https://www.mtgsalvation.com/forums/the-game/commander-edh/527113-what-is-considered-mld):

> MLD is mass land destruction, so generally speaking, any card that destroys multiple lands at once. This is usually indiscriminate, so [Ruination](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bRuination%5d) is considered MLD while [Sylvan Primordial](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSylvan%20Primordial%5d) is not. [Back to Basics](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBack%20to%20Basics%5d), and things that prevent you from using lands are not MLD, simply resource denial. At least, that's my take. I don't think the term has made its way into Webster's yet.

So you're right, it's not an official Magic: The Gathering term.

Comment: I followed the top five links from that very google search and not one of them defined the acronym.  I knew it had something to do with land destruction but the actual acronym wasn't becoming apparent.  Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Hmm ... Google will serve different search results to different users, but I didn't expect so much difference.

Comment: Hmm okay, actually the first one does use the term "mass land destruction" right at the beginning but they didn't capitalize it or put the acronym near it so I must have missed it while scanning.  The other four don't use it at all.